# SD Card Unexpectedly removed error

Tags: sd-card, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I have a Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 which I bought 4 months ago....love it!  Decided to add an external SD card......so I bought a 16 G.  After a couple of weeks, I got a notification "SD Card Removed Unexpectedly!" Of course I never removed the card but I could not get the tablet to recognize my SD card.  In doing research, I noticed that the instruction said I need a Class 10 card, so not being sure I had a class 10, I went out and bought a 32 G Class 10.  Worked beautifully for a week and the error returned......intermittently  In turning on the tab, I never know if the message is there and I can see the card on my tab (at times).....other times I can't.

If I put the SD card in a reader connected to my PC, it is fine.  I complained to Samsung and they said I can return it for repair since it is under warranty.   Do anyone know if Samsung CAN repair this problem?   I don't want to waste the money or time if it is not going to do any good..... Also have anyone discovered a fix or cause of this problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing and reseating the card in the tablet?

Comment: We've got [10 questions with this issue](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=SD+Card+Removed+Unexpectedly). Please especially check with: [My SD card was removed unexpectedly and won't work anywhere](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47263/16575) / [SD card problem, card gets suddenly removed and later added- Sony Xperia X8](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14876/16575).

Comment: Yes - I removed and re-seated the card.  It hasn't made any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is withe SD Card slot on the device. Return your device to SAMSUNG for repair or replacement.